# How to display the product grid as a dropdown list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

We're selling virtual services. The products are well implemented as `Variable Virtual Products`. However it doesn't make sense to display them in a Store as a grid with large thumbnails. Is there any way (or ready-made template) that would display the product loop as a dropdown list?

To be more specific, we sell ASO services by countries. Each country is a product. It would make much more sense to have a form that can be filled and then the country would be offered as a dropdown list. The customizations on the product (right now in the single-product page) could be on the main form.

The provisional store is in [asoranking1.com/shop](https://asoranking1.com/shop/)

I have little experience in WooCommerce templating so please don't omit any rookie detail in your answer.

Comment: Create a dropdown menu with the style you want and then implement functionality to fill dynamically that list with the products. If you create the menu, i can help you with the filling.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos How do I implement the functionality? I do so in the woocommerce template file?

Comment: Yes in the template file..